# Problem in mail() function

Tags: php, email

I have tried to send mail from my new php website. Mail is delivering but I'm not getting the subject and From fields correctly.

```
<?php
define('incall', true);

if(!@include_once('config.php'))
{
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    exit;
}

$to=$_POST['to'];
$message    = str_replace('{link}', $download_path.$_POST['filename'].'.mp3', $email_body);
$headers  = "From: ".$emailfrom_name." <".$emailfrom_address.">\r\n"
                 ."Return-Path: ".$emailfrom_address."\r\n";
$subject=$_POST['subject']

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))header("location:mailsent.php");

exit('Error! Can not be send.');
?>
```

Could you please check and answer ?

Comment: first echo the values $_POST['subject'] and $emailfrom_name and see whether you are getting the values here and not

Comment: What do you mean "not getting correctly"? What exactly do you get, and what do you expect to get?

Comment: I'm getting the mail. But the From is found to be 'unknown' :(

Comment: Thanks everyone. I got the problem got solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this is not a typo ??

```
$message    = str_replace('{link}', $download_path.$_POST['filename'].'.mp3', $email_body);
$headers  = "From: ".$emailfrom_name." <".$emailfrom_address.">\r\n"
                 ."Return-Path: ".$emailfrom_address."\r\n";
```

**$subject=$_POST['subject']**

`if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))header("location:mailsent.php")`;

semi colon missing

Comment: Thanks. Problem was in the "$headers  = "From: ".$emailfrom_name." <".$emailfrom_address.">\r\n"
                 ."Return-Path: ".$emailfrom_address."\r\n";"

Answer (score 0):

I built a class for this - you can get it at:
http://www.kaiesh.com/65/sending-html-composite-email-in-php-using-objects

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using just `"\n"` instead of `"\r\n"` in the $headers string?